# search line of text for EACH item returned by split in c#

Tags: c#, logging, strip, logfile

I'm trying to read my apache log and do some processing with it.  I use a string split function which contains log lines which refer to me in so way.  I want to remove those lines.  The code below shows that I've got.  It only removes "127.0.0.1" but all the "192.168.1.x" lines appear.

How do I remove EVERY split string?

```
        public void GetTheLog()
    {
        string path = "c:\\program files\\Zend\\apache2\\logs\\access.log";
        string path2 = @"access.log";
        int pos;
        bool goodline = true;

        string skipIPs = "127.0.0.1;192.168.1.100;192.168.1.101;192.168.1.106;67.240.13.70";
        char[] splitchar = { ';' };
        string[] wordarray = skipIPs.Split(splitchar);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path2);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            // initialize goodline for each line of reader result
            goodline = true;
            for (j = 0; j < wordarray.Length; j++)
            {
                pos = -10;
                srch = wordarray[j];
                ln = line.Substring(0,srch.Length);
                pos = ln.IndexOf(srch);
                if (pos >= 0) goodline = false;
            }
            if (goodline == true)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(line);
                listBox2.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }

        // Clean up
        reader.Close();
        fs.Close();
        listBox1.Items.Add(path2);
        tw.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var logPath = @"c:\program files\Zend\apache2\logs\access.log";
var skipIPs = "127.0.0.1;192.168.1.100;192.168.1.101;192.168.1.106;67.240.13.70";
var filters = skipIPs.Split(';');
var goodlines = File.ReadLines(logPath)
                    .Where(line => !filters.Any(f => line.Contains(f)));
```

Then you can

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"access.log", goodlines);
```

And it also looks like you're dumping the lines into a listbox

```
listBox2.Items.AddRange(goodlines.Select(line=> new ListItem(line)).ToArray());
```

Also, since your `skipIPs` are just a static string, you could refactor a little and just do

```
var filters = new []{"127.0.0.1","192.168.1.100","192.168.1.101",...};
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had to modify your reply slightly.  I was getting the "file can not be accessed ... in use by another program" error message so I downloaded it to a temporary file as I was doing originally and then added your suggestions applying them to the temporary file.  That did the trick!

Comment: @DaveJaswaye Super, glad to hear it.  As you are new, think about marking this as the correct answer or voting it up.

Answer (score 0):

arrrrrr din get what you want...

okh let me try if you want to remove all the IPs which are present in your skipIPs from your current file.

then you can simply use....

```
    if(ln==srch)
    {
     goodline = false;
    }
```

instead of

```
    pos = ln.IndexOf(srch);
    if (pos >= 0) goodline = false;
```

inside your for loop.

hope it will jelp you... :)

Comment: Thanks!  (Duhhh!)  I think I was over complicating things.  Got tired reloading the program all the time.